# Cannot find the coulmn name in Angular?

Tags: angular-material

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the error that is visible in the last image attached here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: is the `displayedColumns` (line 22) set somewhere else?... I was able to replicate this error because of incorrect name inside my `displayedColumns` array only

Comment: Also, make sure there are no zero-length characters anywhere in your code. Sometimes, when copying names it might copy it with an invisible character attached to it. So while both names LOOK the same, in fact they are not. Try typing them manually (delete the text within quotation marks WITH the quotation marks and re-type it manually to be sure.